# no se guardan los registros php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que guardar lo que escriba en un input text en una tabla de una base de datos no se guarda nada no se que problema tenga, soy nuevo en esto. estan hechas en un stored procedures las consulta y solo la ejecuto con un query.

```
<?php
include_once '../config-php/sapp_configuration.php';
/*
 * La constante DIR_CLASS, DIR_QUERY, DIR_INCLUDE_HEAD_PHP esta declarada
 * en el archivo define_configuration.php
 */

include_once DIR_QUERY . '/query_jose.php';
/*
 * Inclusion de sentencias que se deben de realizar antes de
 * acceder al servicio
 */
include_once (DIR_INCLUDE_HEAD_PHP . '/head_before_service.php');

if (isset($_POST['request']) && $_POST['request'] != "") {

    switch ($_POST['request']) {

        case 'insertarOperacion':

            /**
             * Reiniciar la variable de sesion
             */
            pResetContRefresh();
            if (isset($_POST['form']['da_descripcion']) or ( $_POST['form']['da_descripcion']) == '') {

                $server = getResponseObjJs('mess-resp-jose-0', [
                    'messageType' => 'warning',
                    'message' => 'No se han enviado parametros de descripcion'
                ]);
                echo json_encode($server->getServerData());
                return;
            }

            try {

                $ds = f_query_jose_001($_POST['da_descripcion']);

//                print_r($ds);

                $server = getResponseObjJs('mess-resp-jose-0', [
                    'objDB' => $ds
                ]);
                echo json_encode($server->getServerData());
                return;
            } catch (Exception $exc) {
                $server = getResponseObjJs('mess-resp-08-2', [
                    'errorCode' => 'try-catch-00001',
                    'tryCatchExceptionString' => $exc->getTraceAsString()
                ]);
                echo json_encode($server->getServerData());
                return;
            }

            break;

        default :

            $server = getResponseObjJs('mess-resp-04-3', [
                'errorCode' => 'default-petition-000008'
            ]);
            echo json_encode($server->getServerData());

            break;
    }
} else {

    $server = getResponseObjJs('mess-resp-04-5', [
        'errorCode' => 'variable-petition-000032'
    ]);
    echo json_encode($server->getServerData());
}

function f_query_jose_001($descripcion) {

    $db = DB;
    $sql = "
        exec sp_insertar_operacion '$descripcion'
        ";
    $ds = new DataStore($db, $sql);
    return $ds;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolvi tenia que negar el isset.

```
if(!isset($_POST['form']['da_descripcion']) or ($_POST['form']['da_descripcion']) == '' )
```